# Get a list of all districts in a country

Tags: here-api

Is it possible to get a list of all districts within a country using the here.com api?

I have tried using the batch Geocoder api and setting the level to district and the country to AUS but it is not returning expected results.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this info from Platform Data Extension
https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/topics/introduction.html